# Translate(Y) vertical center method not working - slightly off center

Tags: html, css, center

I have this simple code to vertically and horizontally center a text element on a page:

```
 body {
   max-width: 1200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .container {
   position: relative;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   height: 100vh;
 }

 .center {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

Doing this places the text in the in the vertical center of the container, but ever-so-slightly off-center to the right on the horizontal. I would think "left: 50%" would horizontally center it correctly, no?

Answer (score 7):

Close, but you need to add `translateX` as well. Luckily, there's a nice shorthand for accomplishing both X and Y transform at the same time:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The reason it's slightly off-center is because `left: 50%` pushes the element so that it's left side is at 50% exactly. Adding the `transformX(-50%)` negates that extra space. See the snippet below:

```css
.box-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.center-box {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="center-box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use flexbox then I would recommend using it. It makes this very simple:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 400px; /* Just for the snippet */
  width: 400px; /* Just for the snippet */
  background-color: #f4f4f4; /* Just for the snippet */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Just for the snippet */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    This is centered
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find about flexbox browser support from here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex